# How do I upgrade from Ruby 2.5 to 2.7 on Windows (using Rails 5.2.6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to move off Ruby 2.5 as AWS Elastic Beanstalk has deprecated it. I'll go for 2.7 while staying on Rails 5.2.6. I can't find any documentation about how to do this.

In the past I have downloaded and installed a new version from https://rubyinstaller.org/ but while this ends up being installed according to the Control Panel, it doesn't seem to change the version of Ruby used by Rails as reported by `ruby -v` inside the application folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change ruby version in .ruby-version, Gemfile and in your every config that you set ruby version 2.5 to 2.7.
2. bundle install.
3. Test it

In my case,
i would change

1. .ruby-version
2. Gemfile
3. .rubocop.yml
4. Dockerfile
5. .circleci/config.yml

Comment: Thanks but steps 1 + 2 alone don't work. When I run `bundle install`, I get `Your Ruby version is 2.5.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6`. There is clearly something else I need to do. I am not using Rubocop, Docker or CircleCI.

Comment: i see. in that case, you should search for 2.5.3 in all files of projects and change it to 2.6.x. be careful not to change other gem version that is 2.5.3.

Comment: You need to change the ruby version in the Gemfile as well as the `.ruby-version` file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, which worked:

1. Manually edit **.ruby-version** (as recommended by @togi) to `ruby-2.6.7`.
2. Manually edit **Gemfile** (as recommended by @togi) to `ruby '2.6.7'`.
3. Download and install https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/RubyInstaller-2.6.7-1/rubyinstaller-devkit-2.6.7-1-x64.exe into an empty folder. This link came from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/.
4. During the installation, ensure that the `Add Ruby executables to your PATH` option is selected.
5. During the installation, press `ENTER` when prompted to choose a MSYS2 option.
6. Restart the PC.
7. Go into the Rails folder and verify that Rails is using the correct version by typing `ruby -v`.